# How to avoid or neglect the retrieving image while inserting into the phpmyadmin in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am new to php and I am getting an error:

> Could not retrieve image: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

but I don't want to retrieve the image, I want to avoid it. So, how to resolve this?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    header("location:index.php");
}

if(!empty($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    $uidval = $_SESSION['uid'];
}

$uidval="";

if((isset($_GET['user_avatar'])) && (!empty($_GET['user_avatar']))) {
    $user_avatar = $_GET['user_avatar'];    
}

$getImage = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT user_avatar FROM user WHERE uid=" . $uidval) or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($db));

$path=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getImage) or die("Could not fetch array : " .mysqli_error($db));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few bugs:

1. `$uidval="";` must be above `if(!empty($_SESSION['uid'])) {...` in
   other way the `$uidval` always will be an empty string.
2. If `$uidval` is empty, then you must skip the query to DB.

Example:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["username"])) {
    header("location:index.php");
    exit;
}


$uidval = !empty($_SESSION['uid']) ? $_SESSION['uid'] : '';

if(!empty($_GET['user_avatar'])) {
    $user_avatar = $_GET['user_avatar'];    
}

$path = '';
if (!empty($uidval)) {
    $getImage = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT user_avatar FROM user WHERE uid=" . $uidval) or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($db));

    $path=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getImage) or die("Could not fetch array : " .mysqli_error($db));
}
```